# Specifying relative path in application.properties in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

Is there a way we can lookup file resources using relative path in application.properties file in Spring boot application as specified below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:${project.basedir}/db/init
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@membersound answer is just breaking up the hardcoded path in 2 parts, not dynamically resolving the property. I can tell you how to achieve what you're looking for, but you need to understand is that there is **NO** `project.basedir` when you're running the application as a jar or war. Outside the local workspace, the source code structure doesn't exist.

If you still want to do this for testing, that's feasible and what you need is to manipulate the `PropertySource`s. Your simplest option is as follows:

Define an `ApplicationContextInitializer`, and set the property there. Something like the following:

```
    public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext appCtx) {
        try {
            // should be /<path-to-projectBasedir>/build/classes/main/
            File pwd = new File(getClass().getResource("/").toURI());
            String projectDir = pwd.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParent();
            String conf = new File(projectDir, "db/init").getAbsolutePath();
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put("spring.datasource.url", conf);
            MapPropertySource mapPropertySource = new MapPropertySource("db-props", props);
            appCtx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(mapPropertySource);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }}
```

Looks like you're using Boot, so you can just declare `context.initializer.classes=com.example.MyApplicationContextInitializer` in your `application.properties` and Boot will run this class at startup.

**Words of caution** again:

1. This will not work outside the local workspace as it depends on the source code structure.
2. I've assumed a Gradle project structure here `/build/classes/main`. If necessary, adjust according to your build tool.
3. If `MyApplicationContextInitializer` is in the `src/test/java`, `pwd` will be `<projectBasedir>/build/classes/test/`, not `<projectBasedir>/build/classes/main/`.

Answer (score 15):

I'm using spring boot to build a upload sample, and meet the same problem, I only want to get the project root path. (e.g. /sring-boot-upload)

I find out that below code works:

```
upload.dir.location=${user.dir}\\uploadFolder
```

Comment: Who said the upload folder would be under the home directory?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar do we have a standard to this?

Comment: Any resource should be part of the project

Answer (score 0):

```
your.basedir=${project.basedir}/db/init
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:${your.basedir}

@Value("${your.basedir}")
private String file;

new ClassPathResource(file).getURI().toString()
```

Comment: does ${project.basedir} work within Spring container

Comment: Receive `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could
 not resolve placeholder 'basedir' in string value "jdbc:hsqldb:file:${basedir}/db/init"`

Comment: so you have a variable before declared named `basedir=...`? than it should work. of course it must be declared before reusing the placehodler.

Comment: This is just breaking up the hardcoded path in 2 parts. What the OP is looking for is a property that Boot can resolve, not what a user configures.